# LiveSASSCompile how to compile with subfolder

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, compilation

is possible to LiveSASSCompile compile css with subfolder of scss folder.

*/scss/main.scss* to */css/main.css*
this i know
but when i make subfolder into **scss** folder, i need compile same subfolder into **css** folder

*/scss/subpage/something.scss* to make */css/subpage/something.scss* but not */css/something.scss*

````
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "/css/"
        }
    ]```
````